# Dynamically create Ruby class with ActiveRecord connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, activerecord, metaprogramming

I'm attempting to dynamically create a Class and assign one of several database connections to each Class.

I'm working with anywhere between two or three databases which change over time, therefore, I'm hesitant to store each connection string in a separate Class and inherit from it instead of ActiveRecord::Base.

The following throws an error "RuntimeError: Anonymous class is not allowed.", but I'm not sure how to work around it or if there are better alternatives.

```
  class ClassFactory
    def self.create_class(new_class, table, db_connection)

      c = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
        db = db_connection
        self.table_name = table
        establish_connection(:adapter => db.database_type, :host => db.host, :database => db.database, :username => db.username, :password => db.password).connection
      end

      Module.const_set new_class, c
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set `establish_connection` for model dynamically:

database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  username: root
  password: 
  database: example_development

oracle_development:
  adapter: oracle
  username: root
  password: 
  database: example_oracle_development
```

And in any place of code you may change db connection of your model:

```
User.establish_connection "oracle_#{RAILS_ENV}".to_sym
```

Also you can create model classes dynamically:

```
class ClassFactory
  def self.create_class(new_class, table, connection_name)

    Object.const_set(new_class, Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) {})
    new_class.constantize.table_name = table
    new_class.constantize.establish_connection(connection_name)

  end
end

ClassFactory.create_class('NewUser', 'users', :development)
```

After that `NewUser` class will be available to use.

This version works in both Rails 5.0 and 3.2.

Comment: By my reading of the source, this shouldn't work; the very first line of `ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling#establish_connection` is `raise "Anonymous class is not allowed." unless name`, before it takes a single look at the parameters you passed in. Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: Looks like code will work only in Rails 3.2 or older. [establish connection source](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionHandler/establish_connection). Give me a second, i will try to make it work in new Rails.

Comment: Interesting, I was looking at `ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling#establish_connection`, not `ActiveRecord::ConnectionPool::ConnectionHandler#establish_connection`. Gotta love confusingly similar names for things.

Answer (score 4):

Per [`ActiveRecord::ConnectionHandling#establish_connection`'s source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/92703a9ea5d8b96f30e0b706b801c9185ef14f0e/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb#L48), you can't establish a connection from a class for which `name` doesn't return a truthy value.

Now, you are assigning the class to a constant using `const_set`, and that will give it a name. But you need to do that *before* you call `establish_connection`:

```
class ClassFactory
  def self.create_class(new_class, table, db_connection)
    c = Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) do
      db = db_connection
      self.table_name = table
    end

    Module.const_set new_class, c
    c.establish_connection(:adapter => db.database_type, :host => db.host, :database => db.database, :username => db.username, :password => db.password).connection
  end
end
```

Also, do you really want `Module.const_set(...)`? That will result in a class named `Module::Foo`. Possibly you just want `Object.const_set(...)` (which just gives `Foo`)? Or even `const_set(...)`, so you get `ClassFactory::Foo`?

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. You're right, I didn't want that.